# Save pandas dataframe in kdb/q

Tags: pandas, kdb

What is the best way to save a pandas dataframe in kdb? Are there any libraries that can make it easier?

The below code can apparently be used to loas something from kdb, but how do I save a dataframe into it?

```
from qpython import qconnection

with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
    ds = q('(1i;0Ni;3i)', pandas = True)
    print(ds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a dataframe in KDB+ with qPython one can use the `sync` method of the `QConnection` class. Set the first parameter to a string defining a q function that assigns its parameter to a global variable and send the dataframe as the second parameter. Something like this:

```
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym':['abc','def','ghi'],'price':[10.1,10.2,10.3]})
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
    q.sync('{t::x}',df)
```

Note that you need to use a double colon `::` in the function definition so that the parameter is assigned to a global variable `t` rather that a local variable.

Comment: I get this error: `QWriterException: Unable to serialize type: <class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>`

Comment: Can anyone help? I received this: SystemError: <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'> returned a result with an error set

Comment: Note that in qPython release 2.0.0 the `sync` and `async` methods of the QConnection class got renamed `sendSync` and sendAsync, resp.

Answer (score 5):

Using a mock table from [Pandas Integration](http://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html)

```
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, pandas = True) as q:

 df =  q('flip `name`iq`fullname!(`Dent`Beeblebrox`Prefect;98 42 126;("Arthur Dent";"Zaphod Beeblebrox"; "Ford Prefect"))')
```

This pulls a table built in kdb back in python as a pandas dataframe. The following method saves the table down in memory:

```
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, pandas = True) as q:

  q('{`t set x}', df)
```

Some more information on how data is saved in kdb can be found: [kdb overview](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb+/)

More examples of using set to save data can be found here: [set](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/set)

There is another method of integrating python and q that may be of use to you; [PyQ](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/pyq/) brings the Python and q interpreters into the same process, so that code written in either of the languages operates on the same data.

Comment: thanks, once I have a table in q, how can i filter it by a string? Select.... from name=`something` doesn't seem to work. It just gives giberish output: gS7n`6?8i,M@CZ`Y[5,`mvXP....

Comment: managed to upload the dataframe as folows:
                df.meta = MetaData(sym = QSYMBOL_LIST)
                q('set', np.string_(table_name), df)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use embedPy which allows kdb+ and Python to share the same process and memory space

You can find documation on this library in the provide link http://code.kx.com/q/ml/embedpy/

See below an example implemented in kdb+

```
    q)/ Create kdb+ table
    q)n:100;show 5#qtab:([]scol:n?`AAA`BBB`CCC;icol:n?100;fcol:n?1f)
       scol icol vcol     
      -------------------
       CCC  59   0.3927524
       AAA  30   0.5170911
       CCC  85   0.5159796
       AAA  89   0.4066642
       AAA  23   0.1780839
    q)
    q)/ Load embedPy and import pandas/DataFrame
    q)\l p.q
    q)df:(pd:.p.import`pandas)`:DataFrame
    q)
    q)/ Initialize DataFrame object
    q)/ print is built in embedpy
    q)print df[qtab][`:head]5
          fcol  icol scol
   0  0.392752    59  CCC
   1  0.517091    30  AAA
   2  0.515980    85  CCC
   3  0.406664    89  AAA
   4  0.178084    23  AAA
    q)/ need to reorder the columns
    q)print ptab:df[qtab][@;cols qtab]
       scol  icol      fcol
    0   CCC    59  0.392752
    1   AAA    30  0.517091
    2   CCC    85  0.515980
    3   AAA    89  0.406664
    4   AAA    23  0.178084
    q)/ and converting back to kdb+
    q)/ need to convert it to a dict like 
    q)5#flip ptab[`:to_dict;`list]`
      scol  icol fcol     
     --------------------
      "CCC" 59   0.3927524
      "AAA" 30   0.5170911
      "CCC" 85   0.5159796
      "AAA" 89   0.4066642
      "AAA" 23   0.1780839
   q)/ can also use but slower
   q)5#ptab[`:to_dict;`records]`
     scol  icol fcol     
    --------------------
     "CCC" 59   0.3927524
     "AAA" 30   0.5170911
     "CCC" 85   0.5159796
     "AAA" 89   0.4066642
     "AAA" 23   0.1780839
  q)/ Consider keyed table
  q)show qktab:select by scol from qtab
    scol| icol fcol      
    ----| ---------------
    AAA | 35   0.3410485 
    BBB | 61   0.5548864 
    CCC | 0    0.07347808
  q)/ print as dataframe format
  q)/ reordering columns to be the same as qktab
  q)print pktab:df[qktab][@;cols qktab]
   scol  icol      fcol
0  AAA    35  0.341049
1  BBB    61  0.554886
2  CCC     0  0.073478
  q) / convert it to a dataframe keyed table
  q) / setting the index to become the keyed column
  q)
  q)print pktab:pktab[`:set_index]keys qktab
        icol      fcol
 scol                
 AAA     35  0.341049
 BBB     61  0.554886
 CCC      0  0.073478

 q) / converting back to kdb+
 q) / need to `reset_index` to return full table
 q) / then key the table 
 q)(`$pktab[`:index.names]`)xkey flip pktab[`:reset_index][][`:to_dict;`list]`
 scol | icol fcol      
 -----| ---------------
 "AAA"| 35   0.3410485 
 "BBB"| 61   0.5548864 
 "CCC"| 0    0.07347808
```