# How can I commit a dataframe to kdb as a new table?

Tags: python, pandas, kdb, qpython

I'm aware of this question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101675/save-pandas-dataframe-in-kdb-q), however as a new q-bie I am still quite confused with how to create and insert a new table using q.

My problem: I have a dataframe and I am using qPython to connect to kdb. I want to write this dataframe to kdb as a new table.

My question: it seems like I could do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym':['abc','def','ghi'],'price':[10.1,10.2,10.3]})
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
    q.sync('{t::x}',df)
```

But what is this `{t::x}` here? would t be my table name? and what would x be?

How do I specify column types and size restrictions or they are not needed? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to note that if you are using qPython 2.* it should be q.sendSync instead of q.sync.

[q.sendSync(kdbquery, parameters)](https://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queries.html#synchronous-queries)

```
q.sendSync("{t::x}", df)
{} function syntax
: assignment like = in python
:: global assignment so that the table is defined outside of the function
t is the variable name / table name 
x is the parameter as q/kdb can use implied notation for x,y,z. You could use explicit notation like so "{[x]t::x}"
```

No need to worry about column types as kdb will automatically interpret these and can be changed with a qSQL update statement. [Heres a handy kx reference card for datatypes.](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/)

There is no column size limit as such but there is a limit of 2GB of data over IPC. Edit: (3.4+ kdb has a 1TB IPC limit)